# Hyperparameter estimation on gaussian regression using elastic net

Tags: r, multiple-regression, hyperparameter, elastic-net

I have been tasked with explaining how a set of 50 environmental variables can affect 300 plus measures of anatomical regions.  I am thinking of using gaussian regression as it can handle multiple predictors and fitting it with elastic net using glmnet. ([Tutorial on how to do this here](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/482594_1ad8bd60595d4f9a8f65c3a57a8ce96a.html#multiresponse-gaussian-example))

My question is if there is a formalized way to perform hyperparameter selection for the alpha value?  Is there a community standard on how to chose the optimal value?

Comment: "explaining how ... environmental variables can affect ... anatomical regions" sounds inferential.  "fitting with elastic net" sounds predictive.  You can use the training-validation-test process for selecting hyperparameters and this can work when aiming for predictive models while making inferences difficult to justify

Comment: @Henry But dosen't gaussian regression return weights like linear regression?  They are different because they are distributions but the glmnet package does return a list of betas https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/482594_1ad8bd60595d4f9a8f65c3a57a8ce96a.html#multiresponse-gaussian-example

Comment: That was not quite my point.  You seem to be planning to use algorithms which have been demonstrated to (sometimes) be useful for predictions, and then use the results for inference.  I am not sure that last step is always justifiable

Comment: @Henry Eventually we will be using this model (whatever methods we settle on) to predict a "impact score" on the individual would that be a more appropriate use of the gaussian regression?